# Prism - WPF/Silverlight view-model reuse

Tags: wpf, silverlight, assemblies, prism

Is it possible to reuse my models/view-models that I create in a separate assembly using Prism?

Comment: The simple answer is yes. Are you having specific problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Models and view-models in modules are after all just C# class in DLLs.

The only requirement is that they be loaded before you try to use them :) If you use MEF that load happens automagically, else just ensure your module catalog specifies the right load order.

**Note: this does assume you are using Unity to register and create your Models and View-Models, otherwise you might as well share a static library of Models and View-Models with all your modules but link it only to the one of the early loaded modules.*